# dynamically android button style

Tags: android, button

I want to give some styles to a Android button **dynamically** , based on what integer value entered. for example if user enter 25 my button shape will change to **"quarter of a circle"**. like below picture.
[quarter of a circle image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otwkW.png)

---

I try to use

```
GradientDrawable shape=new GradientDrawable();
shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
```

but i can't find useful method for make `quarter of Oval`

---

In other words i want to make a clickable `pieChart`
don't offer me `github.io` libraries.

---

**Please read this notes.**
 1. I know how to used `<selector>` element and change button style based on that's state.
 2.  I know that how to  using `<shape>` `drawable`  resource. but I need change shape based on what value, user enter.

Comment: What had you tried so far?  Where did you failed?

Comment: thank's for you'r notice . I edit it

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean Edit Text View as you can not enter text on it. You can do this programmatically. You need to use instance of button as a reference and add a `TextWatcher` to your edit text view and add the if statement in there.

Use the following as an example:

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.<id of button>);
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.<id of edit text view>);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i,int i1, int i2) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                if(charSequence.equals("25")){
                    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.<id of custom button>);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
        });
```

Comment: not only 25  . i mean if user enter 54.5 ? what i do ... i want to make pie chart that can clickable

Comment: Use a `switch(charSequesnce)` statement for all your different cases.